# Doctrine в Symphony и значение по умолчанию

Tags: symfony, doctrine2, doctrine, symfony4

Подскажите, как в yml файле описать значение по умолчанию?
Пишу:

```
App\Entity\Producting:
  type: entity
  table: producting
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }

  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
    cost:
      type: integer
    amount:
      type: float
    comment:
      type: text
      default: texting...
    answer:
      type: text
      default: "answering..."
```

Но при добавлении новой записи в таблицу, но поля с определёнными значениями по умолчанию таковые не принимают ни при добавлении в ручную SQL запросом, ни php-кодом:

```
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = new Producting();
    $product->setName($name);
    $product->setCost($cost);
    $product->setAmount($amount);
    $entityManager->persist($product);
```

Собственно как определить значение по умолчанию? в YML-файле?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669338/set-entity-field-default-value-using-yml так не работает?

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую таки использовать аннотации. В будущем вы оцените удобство и необходимость этого подхода, если пока что он вам кажется чуждым. Да и в best practice вы об этом можете прочесть.

Comment: В других фреймворках я использую именно аннотацию, но данный я сейчас изучаю и хочу разобраться в простейших и очевидных вещах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос снимается.

Цитирую документацию:

*Doctrine does not support to set the default values in columns through the "DEFAULT" keyword in SQL. This is not necessary however, you can just use your class properties as default values. These are then used upon insert:*

```
class User
{
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    private $algorithm = "sha1";
    private $status = self:STATUS_DISABLED;
}
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column

Answer (score 0):

```
active:
  column: active
  type: boolean
  nullable: false
  options:
    default: true
```